Modules over quotient algebras
When I was reading "Basic Representation Theory of Algebras" by F. U. Coelho et al., I had trouble uderstanding the module $_{A}A_{B}$. In page 138, the author introduces two functors $- \otimes_{B} A_{A}$ and $\text{Hom}_{B}(_{A}A_{B},-)$ from $\text{mod }B$ to $\text{mod }A$, see the picture below. Here $A$ is an algebra and $B$ is a quotient algebra of $A$. All algebras are (possibly noncommutative) associative algebras over a field, and all modules are right modules unless otherwise specified.

From what I understand, we need a $B-A-$bimodule $_{B}M_{A}$ to make $- \otimes_{B} M$ a functor from $\text{mod }B$ to $\text{mod }A$, and an $A-B-$bimodule $_{A}N_{B}$ to make $\text{Hom}_{B}(N,-)$ a functor from $\text{mod }B$ to $\text{mod }A$. However, I can't figure out how $A$ becomes a $B$ module (whether left or right). Since $B$ is a quotient of $A$, I know that $B$ is an $A$ module, but the converse is not obvious to me. Can anyone help me with this?

That looks like a mistake to me.

Now I have a possible explanation. In general, $A$ is not a module over $B$. But in later subsections the author is mainly interested in a spectial case: $A$ is a split extension of $B$, that is, $A\cong B \oplus E$, where $B$ is a subalgebra of $A$ and $E$ is a two-sided ideal of $A$. With this additional condition, $A$ is clearly a $B$-module. Maybe the author forgot mentioning this in subsection $\mathrm{III}.4.1$.
